# Newman(Postman) - Import collection from a URL under windows authentication

Tags: postman, windows-authentication, ntlm, newman

I'm trying to run newman with postman collection from a url as mentioned in this [link](https://www.getpostman.com/docs/v6/postman/collection_runs/command_line_integration_with_newman) .

```
newman run http://localhost:62254/api/postman
```

Only catch is that the url is under windows authentication, so I'm getting a 401 Unauthorized response, causing newman to fail with below error.

```
the url "http://localhost:62254/api/postman" did not provide valid JSON data
```

I tried passing the credentials with the request like below. But it didn't work.

http://username:password@localhost:62254/api/postman

If I directly hit the endpoint with Postman using 'NTLM Authentication' feature it works fine. But I'm not sure if I can use this with newman to get the collection itself.

Comment: Not sure that I completely understand the question you’re asking but have you at least tried using the `-k` flag after the url?

Comment: @DannyDainton With -k flag also I'm getting the same error. In our application we are dynamically generating the collection through an API. But that API is is hosted under windows authentication. Any thoughts?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We were not able to find any option in Postman/Newman. So finally we made this URL alone (http://localhost:62254/api/postman) open to Anonymous Authentication in the web server.